# How to select other (sibling) elements CSS?

Tags: css

I have a navbar that looks something like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

when I `:hover` one item I want to change the styling of the other two. What CSS selector can I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply the hover on the parent element and exclude the hovered child:

```
.navbar-nav:hover li:not(:hover) {    
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: looks perfect! how is this supported?

Comment: As these are normal CSS3 selectors it should work fine across modern browsers. Made a quick test on IE9 and I can confirm that it works there.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the hover to the nav wrapper and style all the `li` children. Then, apply a hover to the `li` and style it to be different: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0yqrbr/1/)

```
ul.nav:hover li.nav-item {
    background: green;
}
li.nav-item:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:not` selector to apply style on the NOT hovered elements without having to style them when they're not hovered:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a:not(:hover) {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ul:hover li {
    background: red;
}

ul li:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

simple [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/19ad3cqk/)

also described in [Hover on “Everything But”](https://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this purely with css. However, you could do this easily with jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav nav-item:hover').siblings().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```